# Connect tomcat through socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have been trying to communicate to tomcat using socket. I am forming the HTTP message and writing that to the outputStream. The connection gets established successfully but i am not receiving any response. When i am trying to connect through telnet with the same message able to get the response. Please find the code snippet below and point what i am missing.

```
                String text1 = text.getText();
                String text2 = text_1.getText();
                String address = combo.getText();
                System.out.println("Text1 =" + text1 + " Text2 = " + text2 + " Address = "+address);
            try{
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8082);
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //U need to post actual HTTP MESSAGE HERE
                StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                requestBuilder.append("GET").append(SPACE).append(FORWARD_SLASH).append("SayHello").append(FORWARD_SLASH).append("SayHello").append("?")
                .append("text1=").append(text1).append("&text2=").append(text2).append(NEWLINE)/*.append(SPACE).append("HTTP/1.1").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("accept").append(COLON).append(SPACE).append("text/plain;").append(SPACE).append("text/html").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("accept-language").append(COLON).append("en-US").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("connection").append(COLON).append("keep-alive").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("host").append(COLON).append("localhost").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("user-agent").append(COLON).append("MyUCBrowser").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("content-length").append(COLON).append("0").append(NEWLINE)
                .append("connection-type").append(COLON).append("text/plain").append(NEWLINE)*/;

                /*box.setMessage(requestBuilder.toString());
                box.open();*/
                System.out.println(requestBuilder.toString());

                outToServer.writeUTF(requestBuilder.toString());
                String tempResp;
                while ((tempResp = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(tempResp);
                }
                System.out.println(builder.toString().length() > 0 ? builder.toString() : "Anup Kalane!!!");
                text_2.setText(builder.toString());
                socket.close();
                display.dispose();
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

For the convenience also attaching the servlet...It's very basic one. I just created it for testing purpose.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text1 = request.getParameter("text1") != null ? request.getParameter("text1") : "NULL";
        String text2 = request.getParameter("text2") != null ? request.getParameter("text2") : "NULL";
        System.out.println("Hello");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("<HTML><BODY><H1>HELLO\nText1 = "+text1+"\nText2 = "+text2+"</H1></BODY></HTML>");
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: where in your code does the program stop, or does it somehow make it all the way through?  Also, what happens if you strip out all that append stuff and just send a few newlines.  Do you get an error response then?  If not, then you have much more fundamental problems.  If so, slowly start adding your appends back in until it stops working and figure out why that one breaks it.

Comment: sir where my program my ends that's not important, the snippet I posted it's a part of a huge SWT application which actually starts and stops very normally. NO I don't receive ne error response at all. BTW thanks for your nice help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using writeUTF() where you should be using write(), but why are you doing all this at all? Why aren't you using HttpURLConnection or an HTTP client of some sort? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. BTW write() also din't help and writeUTF() also invokes write() method only. Actually it's not a matter of reinvention of wheel, we are trying to develop something from where we need to connect popular app servers through socket only.

Comment: Not in the slightest. writeUTF() writes a 16-bit length word and then the data, in a special format. See the Javadoc. If it was the same as write() it wouldn't exist, would it? writeUTF() writes a format that only readUTF() can understand, and Tomcat doesn't do readUTF() when reading requests. What you're doing is indeed re-inventing the wheel, and apparently without enough knowledge to do so: for example, you aren't encoding the request parameter names or values. You should have a good look at the Apache HTTP client before proceeding any further with this.